# Why changing GitHub repository language not working?

Tags: git, github, label, gitattributes, github-linguist

i have been made a repository in GitHub with as Xcode project with Objective-C language.
Beside **.gitignore** file in root of my project made **.gitattributes** file and set this code in it:

```
* linguist-vendored
*.objective-c linguist-vendored=false
```

But does not show any language in Github homepage.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of `.gitattributes` rules must match files in the repository. Unless your Objective-C files have `.objective-c` for file extension, the above will not work. The following should work:

```
* linguist-vendored
*.c linguist-vendored=false
*.h linguist-vendored=false
*.m linguist-vendored=false
```

Answer (score 0):

The GitHub language indicator cannot be manually set.

It shows a breakdown of the files in your repository and the languages it determines they are written in.

See [about repository languages](https://help.github.com/articles/about-repository-languages/) on GitHub.